# PHP View data from a single record by clicking on the view button

Tags: php, mysql

I have two pages students_list.php and students_profile.php

On students_list.php i have a table showing all records of all students and the VIEW button which when clicked it should open the students_profile.php page and get all the data from the single record selected based on the std_id

UPDATE: So now i get the id http://localhost/sms/student_profiles.php?std_id=3 when i click on the VIEW button but i am still not retrieving the data from this record selected

This is the code for students_list.php

```
<?php
require_once 'include/database/connect.php';

try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host_db;dbname=$name_db", $user_db, $pass_db);                                 
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM students';
    $q = $pdo->query($sql);
    $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Could not connect to the database $name_db :" . $e->getMessage());
    }
?>
<table id="data-table-default" class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th width="1%">#</th>
    <th width="1%" data-orderable="false"></th>
    <th>Name & Surname</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
    <th>Faculty</th>
    <th>Semester</th>
    <th>Mobile</th>
    <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <?php while ($row = $q->fetch()): ?>
    <tr class="odd gradeX">
    <td width="1%" class="f-s-600 text-inverse"><?php echo ($row['std_id']) ?></td>
    <td width="1%" class="with-img"><?php echo ($row['std_status']) ?></td>
    <td><?php echo ($row['std_name']) ?></td>
    <td><?php echo ($row['std_gender']) ?></td>
    <td><?php echo ($row['std_faculty']) ?></td>
    <td><?php echo ($row['std_semester']) ?></td>
    <td><?php echo ($row['std_mobile']) ?></td>
    <td align="right">
    <a href="student_profiles.php?std_id=<?php echo $row['std_id']; ?>" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i> View</a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and below this is the student_profile.php

```
<?php
require_once('include/database/sharepoint.php');
if(isset($_GET) & !empty($_GET)){
    $std_id = $_GET['std_id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE std_id=$std_id";
    $res = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
}
?>

<h4><?php echo ($row['std_name']) ?></h4>

<div class="d-flex">
    <div class="pr-4"><strong>NATIONAL#</strong> <?php echo ($row['std_number']) ?></div>
    <div class="pr-4"><strong>DOB</strong> <?php echo ($row['std_dob']) ?></div>
    <div class="pr-4"><strong>GENDER</strong> <?php echo ($row['std_gender']) ?></div>
    <div class="pr-4"><strong>MOBILE</strong> <?php echo ($row['std_mobile']) ?></div>
</div>
<div class="pt-1 font-weight-bold">Master's Degree (MBA)</div>
<div>STD# <strong><?php echo ($row['std_id']) ?></strong></div>
<div><a href="#" target="new">email@example.com</a></div>
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is. Is there one?

Comment: So ,what is not `working` ? Did you got any `error` ?

Comment: I would like to view the students profile by clicking on the VIEW button that should then open the students_profile.php page but i dont know how to do that

Comment: In students_profile.php file get the students I'd. $std_id =$_GET['std_id']; And use in your query like SELECT * FROM students' where std_id = $std_id

Comment: @ShivendraSingh can you please show me how this is done

Comment: is there a specific reason why you should use PDO in the first page and Mysqli in the second?

Comment: btw. your issue is that you miss to **fetch** the data after you execute the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't fecth the data from the query. So $row will never contain the array you expect:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res); //this will populate $row
```

in your code:

```
<?php
require_once('include/database/sharepoint.php');
if(isset($_GET) & !empty($_GET)){
    $std_id = $_GET['std_id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE std_id=$std_id";
    $res = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
}
?>
```